# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error with Workbook.Open

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Trying to write a procedure to open a workbook and complete SUMIFS in the background and store the summed value in variable. Once completed the variables values will be added to another workbook with a table in it.  This is in a effort automate the manual task of open each systemname workbook and adding the filters, and then hand typing the SUMIFS value to the second workbook. Although, the workbook is not getting opened on the *Set FromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open* line. Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestCode()
'===============================================================================================
'Description: Loops through the selected site and adds in the vulnerability totals for each _
    systems
'Originally written by: Troy Pilewski
'Date: 2016-06-30
'===============================================================================================

'Declares variables
Dim ToWorkbook As Workbook, FromWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ToWorksheet As Worksheet, FromWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim WorkingRange As Range, WholeRange As Range, SystemCol As Range, SystemName As Range, _
    DataRange As Range, OwnerCol As Range, CategoryCol As Range, AssetCountCol As Range
Dim VarFromWorkbook As Variant, ShipNameList() As Variant, ShipName As Variant, Owner As Variant
Dim TitleString As String, FilterName As String, CurrentSystemName As String, _
    ShipNames() As String, SelectedShipName As String, Owners() As String, OwnerSelected As String
Dim LastRow As Long, ShipRow As Long, OwnerColNum As Long, CategoryColNum As Long, _
    AssetCountColNum As Long
Dim StartRow As Integer, BoundCounter As Integer, MsgSelection As Integer, _
    ScanFileExist As Integer, CATI As Integer, CATII As Integer, CATIII As Integer, _
    CATIV As Integer
Const RowMultiplyer As Integer = 47

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ToWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ToWorksheet = ToWorkbook.ActiveSheet

LastRow = ToWorksheet.Range("Y:Y").Find( _
    What:="*", _
    After:=ToWorksheet.Range("Y1"), _
    LookAt:=xlByRows, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
).Row

'MsgBox _
'    Prompt:="Y1:Y" & LastRow, _
'    Title:="Ship Range"

ShipNameList = ToWorksheet.Range("Y1:Y" & LastRow).Value

For Each ShipName In ShipNameList
    If Left(ShipName, 3) = "USS" Then
        BoundCounter = BoundCounter + 1
    End If
Next ShipName

ReDim ShipNames(BoundCounter - 1)
BoundCounter = 0

For Each ShipName In ShipNameList
    If Left(ShipName, 3) = "USS" Then
        ShipNames(BoundCounter) = ShipName
'        Debug.Print ShipNames(BoundCounter)
        BoundCounter = BoundCounter + 1
    Else
'        Debug.Print UBound(ShipNames())
        Exit For
    End If
Next ShipName

TitleString = "Select a ship..."

SelectedShipName = GetChoiceFromChooserForm(ShipNames, TitleString)

If SelectedShipName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ShipRow = ToWorksheet.Range("Y:Y").Find( _
    What:=SelectedShipName, _
    After:=ToWorksheet.Range("Y1"), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True _
).Row

'Debug.Print ShipRow

StartRow = 14

If ShipRow > 1 Then
    StartRow = (RowMultiplyer * (ShipRow - 1)) + StartRow
Else
    StartRow = 14
End If

Set WorkingRange = ToWorksheet.Range("B" & StartRow & ":G" & StartRow + 38)
Set SystemCol = WorkingRange.Columns(2)

'Debug.Print WorkingRange.Address

FilterName = "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls,Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx,All Files (*.*), *.*"
TitleString = "Scan File Selection"

ScanFileExist = MsgBox( _
    Prompt:="Are there scan files to read?", _
    Buttons:=vbYesNo, _
    Title:=TitleString)

Do While ScanFileExist = vbYes
For Each SystemName In SystemCol.Cells
    If IsError(SystemName) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        If SystemName.Offset(0, -1) > 1 Then
            MsgBox _
                Prompt:=SystemName & " is marked 'Do Not Scan'", _
                Title:="Do Not Scan"
            GoTo NextIteration
        Else
            MsgSelection = MsgBox( _
                Prompt:="Is there a scan file for the system: " & SystemName & "?", _
                Buttons:=vbYesNo, _
                Title:=TitleString)
            CATI = 0
            CATII = 0
            CATIII = 0
            CATIV = 0
            If MsgSelection = vbYes Then
                VarFromWorkbook = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                    FileFilter:=FilterName, _
                    FilterIndex:=2, _
                    Title:=TitleString)
                On Error GoTo NextIteration
                Set FromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open( _
                    Filename:=VarFromWorkbook, _
                    UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, _
                    ReadOnly:=False, _
                    Format:=5, _
                    Password:="", _
                    WriteResPassword:="", _
                    IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:="", _
                    Origin:="", _
                    Delimiter:="", _
                    Editable:="", _
                    Notify:="", _
                    Converter:="", _
                    AddToMru:="", _
                    Local:="", _
                    CorruptLoad:=xlNormalLoad)
                Set FromWorksheet = FromWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
                With FromWorksheet
                    LastRow = .Range("A:J").Find( _
                        What:="*", _
                        After:=.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
                    ).Row

                    Set WholeRange = .Range("A2:J" & LastRow)
                    Set DataRange = .Range("A3:J" & LastRow)

                    OwnerColNum = .Range("A:J").Find( _
                        What:="Owner", _
                        After:=.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                    ).Column
                    CategoryColNum = .Range("A:J").Find( _
                        What:="CAT", _
                        After:=.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                    ).Column
                    AssetCountColNum = .Range("A:J").Find( _
                        What:="Not Compliant", _
                        After:=.Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                    ).Column

                    DataRange.Columns(AssetCountCol).Replace _
                        What:="(****%)", _
                        Replacement:=" ", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

                    Owners() = Split( _
                        Expression:="Site,System,Investigation Req'd", _
                        Delimiter:=",", _
                        Limit:=-1, _
                        Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)

                    With WholeRange
                        Set OwnerCol = .Columns(OwnerColNum)
                        Set CategoryCol = .Columns(CategoryColNum)
                        Set AssetCountCol = .Columns(AssetCountColNum)

                        For Each Owner In Owners()
                            OwnerSelected = Owner
                            Debug.Print OwnerSelected

                            With WorksheetFunction
                                CATI = .SumIfs( _
                                    Arg1:=AssetCountCol, _
                                    Arg2:=OwnerCol, _
                                    Arg3:=Owner, _
                                    Arg4:=CategoryCol, _
                                    Arg5:="I")
                                CATII = .SumIfs( _
                                    Arg1:=AssetCountCol, _
                                    Arg2:=OwnerCol, _
                                    Arg3:=Owner, _
                                    Arg4:=CategoryCol, _
                                    Arg5:="II")
                                CATIII = .SumIfs( _
                                    Arg1:=AssetCountCol, _
                                    Arg2:=OwnerCol, _
                                    Arg3:=Owner, _
                                    Arg4:=CategoryCol, _
                                    Arg5:="III")
                                CATIV = .SumIfs( _
                                    Arg1:=AssetCountCol, _
                                    Arg2:=OwnerCol, _
                                    Arg3:=Owner, _
                                    Arg4:=CategoryCol, _
                                    Arg5:="IV")
                            End With
                            Debug.Print CATI
                            Debug.Print CATII
                            Debug.Print CATIII
                            Debug.Print CATIV
                        Next Owner
                    End With
                End With
                If VarFromWorkbook = "False" Then
                End If
            Else: MsgSelection = vbNo
                MsgSelection = MsgBox( _
                    Prompt:="Is there Information Assurance Vulnerabilities for the system: " & SystemName & "?", _
                    Buttons:=vbYesNo, _
                    Title:=TitleString)
                If MsgSelection = vbYes Then
                    VarFromWorkbook = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                        FileFilter:=FilterName, _
                        FilterIndex:=2, _
                        Title:=TitleString)
                Else: MsgSelection = vbNo
                    SystemName.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = CATI
                    SystemName.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = CATII
                    SystemName.Offset(0, 3).Value2 = CATIII
                    SystemName.Offset(0, 4).Value2 = CATIV
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
NextIteration:
Next SystemName
ScanFileExist = MsgBox( _
    Prompt:="Are there any other scan files to read?", _
    Buttons:=vbYesNo, _
    Title:=TitleString)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: The error happens when I get to this line: Set FromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open( _

Comment: File already open.

Comment: As far as I know the file is not already open.

Comment: Check task manager for orphaned Excel processes which might still be hanging around with reference to that workbook. This often happens while developing/debugging if you abort runtime early either via  error or Stop command.

Comment: There is only one Microsoft Excel process still open which is the values need to inserted into, not the one where the SUMIFS need to be performed.

Comment: File in use by another machine/user? If so, you can only open the file in read-only mode, but you're expressly disallowing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117621/discussion-between-troypilewski-and-david-zemens).

Comment: Try this: when the error happens, end your runtime and try to open the same file manually. See if you get any warnings/alerts/etc.

Comment: I'm the only one that has the file that I am trying to open.

Comment: Can't open manually either

Comment: Well there ya go. What happens when you open it manually? You must be getting some sort of warning, prompt, error, etc.

Comment: Also make sure you've enabled alerts & screen updating for your manual test -- if you're code broke because of unhandled exception, then those `Application` settings may persist, either causing further errors or appearance of further errors.

Comment: Closed Excel, Was able to open document manually. Opened the main workbook again, tested again. For the first system that I had a file for it skipped and the second one I received a messgebox with a critical error that all it stated was 400

Comment: Can I email you the documents and you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix that error to find another: The fix was to remove all arguments from the line with the error after UpdateLinks